# Can I have two tables, each with a different REDIPIS.drag drop_option value?

Tags: javascript, redips.drag

I’m using the excellent [REDIPS.drag library](http://www.redips.net/javascript/redips-drag-documentation/) - but I have multiple tables, and I need one of them to have a `drop_option` of `single`, and the other to have a `drop_option` of `multiple`.

Can this be achieved?  (I’m using version 4.x - not upgraded to the new v5 yet.)

Thanks in advance.